# Owlready2 dynamic class generation

Tags: python-3.x, owlready

I am trying to dynamically create a class for an owlready2 ontology. The documentation suggests the following line of code:

```
NewClass = types.new_class("NewClassName", (SuperClass,), kwds = { "namespace" : my_ontology })
```

In my case this equals

```
types.new_class("NewClassName", (onto["ParentClass"],), kwds={'namespace' : onto})
```

However, when I run the above code, I get the following exception:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
    (onto[object.get('owl_dataProperty_parent')],), kwds={'namespace' : onto})
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/types.py", line 62, in new_class
    return meta(name, bases, ns, **kwds)
 TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'namespace
```

I have no idea what went wrong there and after hours of debugging I am still clueless.
I am using Python 3.6.6 and version 0.11 of owlready2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that the "namespace" attribute is not needed at all. So the following works just fine:

```
types.new_class("NewClassName", (onto["ParentClass"],))
```

Even though this does not solve the overall issue, it answered my question.

Additionally, it seams like this is the way to do it in general, cf.[owlready forum](http://owlready.8326.n8.nabble.com/How-to-create-Object-and-Data-Properties-dynamically-td244.html). So maybe it is time to update the documentation.