# How to dynamically create classes and individuals with owlready2?

Tags: python

This is by documentation:

```
NewClass = types.new_class("NewClassName", (SuperClass,), kwds = { "namespace" : my_ontology })
```

I don't understand why the code doesn't work. I have written:

```
NewClass = types.new_class("NewClassName", (Example,), kwds = { "namespace" : onto })
```

I have also try the code that doesn't work from url: [Owlready2 dynamic class generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53397615/owlready2-dynamic-class-generation)

```
types.new_class("NewClassName", (onto["ParentClass"],))
```

I don't understand the expression (onto["ParentClass"],). Then I don't understand how to create dynamically individuals. It is possible to do it?

Can I have a short simple script of example that works with a class and an individual?

Answer (score 2):

1. I have just written that code and tested it:

```
from owlready2 import *

# check that the base class is accessible
print(Thing)  # owl.Thing

my_onto = get_ontology('http://test/qwerty')

with my_onto:
    my_new_class = types.new_class("NewClassName", (Thing,))  # make a class

print(my_new_class)  # qwerty.NewClassName

my_obj = my_new_class("myObjName")  # make an instance

print(my_obj)  # qwerty.myObjName
```

Note to derive custom class from `owlready2.Thing` (as in my case) or any of it's subclasses.

Creating individuals is simple as making ordinal python instances (use variable holding the reference to created class (`my_new_class` in my case) as constructor, so call it to get a new instance). The call is not required to be placed inside the `with my_onto:` block.

So the newly created entities are accessible via:

- `class_var = my_onto.NewClassName`
- `class_var = my_onto["NewClassName"]  # returns None if you pass wrong string`
- `obj_var = my_onto.myObjName`
- `obj_var = my_onto["myObjName"]`

Note that an instance is not created if already exists. So the code below always returns `True`:

```
my_onto["myObjName"] is my_onto["myObjName"]  # True
```

I did that with my Python3.7 and Owlready2 v0.23 recently released (as of `pip install -U owlready2` reported).

2. The code `(onto["ParentClass"],)` just obtains desired base class from the ontology `onto` and packs it into a tuple (note the syntax `(a,)` to create one-element tuple).